# Nokogiri Chokes on Document with unicode char (i think) in title attribute

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, nokogiri

I have a document that looks similar to this (**note the title**):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>Sã�ng Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      Some Text
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When i get this document using Nokogiri using this code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read)
```

The result from Nokogiri is this:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :060 > pp doc
#(Document:0x82e5ed2c {
  name = "document",
  children = [
    #(DTD:0x82e5e994 { name = "HTML" }),
    #(Element:0x82e5e0c0 {
      name = "html",
      attributes = [
        #(Attr:0x82e5e05c {
          name = "xmlns",
          value = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          }),
        #(Attr:0x82e5e048 {
          name = "xmlns:fb",
          value = "http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
          })],
      children = [
        #(Element:0x82e5d8dc {
          name = "head",
          children = [
            #(Element:0x82e5d6d4 {
              name = "title",
              children = [ #(Text "Sã")]
              })]
          })]
      })]
  })
```

To me, it looks like the character AFTER "Sã" causes nokogiri to just choke and think the document has ended.  As you can see the #content div is not included at all.

Anyone know how to deal with this situation?

This is killing me... Thank you!!

Edit:
Upon further research i've found the actual character causing the choke is a unicode null char "\u0000".

Right now i'm thinking i can do something like this:

```
page_content = open(url).read
# Remove null character
page_content.gsub!(/\u0000/, '')
Nokogiri::HTML(page_content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the character after Sã is a valid UTF-8 character?

**Added** There are illegal UTF-8 character sequences. To decode UTF-8 manually, try this [decoder](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder). You can enter the incoming hex and it will tell you what each individual byte means.

A good [overview](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html) of UTF-8. UTF-8 [code chart](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl)

Re: Removing the null character. Your code looks ok, try it out! But in addition, I'd investigate the source of the null in your incoming datastream.

Also, the binary UTF-8 of your Original Post is, in fact, the unknown character symbol--not your original datastream. Here is what is in your post:

```
53 C3 A3 EF BF BD 6E 67
```

Here is the decoding:

```
U+0053 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S character
U+00E3 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH TILDE character (&#x00E3;)
U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER character (&#xFFFD;)  # this is the char used when
                                                   # the orig is not understood.
U+006E LATIN SMALL LETTER N character
U+0067 LATIN SMALL LETTER G character
```

Comment: I am absolutely unsure on that -- is there a way to check?  Also, did you mean UTF-8?

Comment: Updated the initial question with character info.

Comment: Larry, thanks A TON my friend.  These character encoding issues are really tough and sometimes very obscure.  I used a combination of what we both said to figure out what the character was and then ultimately remove it.  I think it came down to my data source just not being clean and injecting non-utf-8 characters in a doc with a utf-8 charset.  Removing those characters cleaned it up.  For anyone reading this at a later time the code i posted to clean out the char does in fact work.